# Least common fixed-point

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders, fixed-point-theorems

I have been reading a book, "Introduction to Lattices and Order", and I'm trying to solve exercise 8.29 as the following in it:

Suppose that $P$ is a complete lattice and let $F$ and $G$ be order-preserving maps. If $F$ and $G$ have a common fixed-point, then they have a least common fixed-point given by $a := \wedge \{x \in P \mid F(x) \le x  \mathop{\&} G(x) \le x \}$.

My proof is:
for all $y \in \{x \in P \mid F(x) \le x  \mathop{\&} G(x) \le x \}$, I have $a \le y$, so $F(a) \le F(y) \le y$ and $G(a) \le G(y) \le y$. Therefore I have $F(a) \le a$ and $G(a) \le a$. Here I want to prove that $a \le F(a)$ and $a \le G(a)$, but it seems hard to do so because I don't assume that F and G are commute.

Could you advise me about this problem?

Comment: You haven't used the assumption that $F$ and $G$ have a common fixed point yet. There must be some use for that lurking in the wings somehow …

Comment: Your definition $a:=\vee \{x \in P \mid F(x) \leq x\; \& \; G(x)\leq x\}$ is not the least common fixed point.  All common fixed points belong to $\{x \in P \mid F(x) \leq x\, \& \, G(x)\leq x\}$.  Taking the join of this set you get a point that is *above* all common fixed points.  The definition you want is $a:= \wedge \{x \in P \mid F(x) \leq x\; \& \; G(x)\leq x\}$.

Comment: @WilliamDeMeo I correct the definition. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bears no resemblance to the first version of this answer.

I’m going to assume that you’ve already seen the [Knaster-Tarski theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem), since it seems unlikely that that exercise would precede it. The map

$$\varphi:P\times P\to P\times P:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\langle F(x),G(y)\rangle$$

is order-preserving, and $P\times P$ is a complete lattice with the usual product order, so by the Knaster-Tarski theorem the set $M$ of fixed points of $\varphi$ is a complete lattice. Let $$\Delta=\{\langle x,x\rangle\in P\times P:x\in P\}\;.$$ Then $M\cap\Delta$ is the set of common fixed points of $F$ and $G$, so by hypothesis $M\cap\Delta\ne\varnothing$. Thus $M\cap\Delta$ has a least element in $M$, which is what we wished to prove.

Comment: Why do $c \le F(c)$ and $c \le G(c)$ hold?

Comment: @skymountain: I’m no longer sure *what* I was thinking at that point. I’ll either fix or delete this in the next day or so.

Comment: I'm sorry for my late response.

Comment: @skymountain: No harm done; coming back to the problem with a fresh eye turned out to be a good thing. I’ve tackled it completely differently this time.

Comment: You answer seems good, but I have one question: why do you know that $M \cap \vartriangle$ has a least element?

Comment: @skymountain: Because $M$ is a complete lattice, and $M\cap\Delta$ is a non-empty subset of $M$.

Comment: Is the least element of $M \cap \Delta$ given by $\wedge (M \cap \Delta)$? If so, why is it in $\Delta$?

Comment: @skymountain: By definition the least element of any set belongs to that set; the only question is whether a set has a least element. The Knaster-Tarski theorem says that every non-empty subset of $M$ has a least element. $M\cap\Delta$ is non-empty by hypothesis. You don’t need to take an infimum, though of course it’s true that the least element of $M\cap\Delta$ is the infimum of $M\cap\Delta$ in $M$ (not necessarily in $P\times P$).

Comment: I understand. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @skymountain: You’re very welcome!